# Bug with Powerbuilder autosize

Tags: text, printing, powerbuilder, autosize

I have problems using autosize height of datawindows in powerbuilder. When the text have many lines sometimes its cut. A pic:

[The text of the first line of the delivery note does not appear complete. Should finish with 'purus nullam.'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNe8l.png)

[Powerbuilder report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ossUl.png)

Sorry for the censored text but is confidential information of my company.

If is possible I want to solve this problem without codes, only modifying the datawindow properties because for the moment I only have permission to check out this datawindows.

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it closing the "detail" band. Autosize works best if the band is completely closed.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late for a reply on this, but....

When you return varchar from SQL to PB, it curtails the number of characters to 255, even though you may have defined your PB column to be 8000 chars.

To overcome this try converting the return value to TEXT:
Convert(Text, return)